# SQL or SharedPreferences, or what?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I want to create an android app for beer Brewing. The app create recipes and load recipes. Each recipe content the ingredients and the amount of each one needed, also include water needed, time of boil and other stuff. In resume each recipe include a lot of Strings (name of ingredients), Integers,Boolean, and double values.

What could be the best method to save this values in the app, and posible share this to other users.?

If each recipe could be storaged as an independent file that's be great.

I am working with Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best solution will be to use SQLite.
It will offer you the possibility to have structured data and also to make searches and filtering much easier.

For the sharing part you can either create a format of the file that is known only by your app (it can be a text or a binary file) or you can use some server side like [parse](http://parse.com) so you can very easy to store the data into a server and notify users about changes and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Its all depends on your flexibility.

**Content Provider** is used to Share data between applications.

**SharedPreference** is used to Store small size of information like "read me" option in Login page, where you store userId & password in SharedPreference to skip login screen in future.

**Sqlite** is used when you have large size of structure data. Sqlite also allows you to use query for searching particular data.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` is for key-value pairs and would not be useful for something like this. Either use an SQLite database, or store files in your app's data directory.

Read more about storage options [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

With SharedPreference you have the most flexibility (no rigid structure) but you also have size (and index count?) limits which you may run into if having lots of recipes.

With sqlite you would have virtually no limit but would have to respect the structure you would need to define. It is also easier to debug and manipulate the data.

Depending on how your app would navigate the data you could even use flat files (one file per recipe using json format for example).

I usually choose sqlite in those cases since it is usually more future proof.